# Open-source cross-platform (or MacOSX) tracking software

Tags: macos, open-source, cross-platform, tracking, geolocation

I'm searching for some software (or some simple scripts or even only code snippets) which:

- is Open Source
- runs in the background
- collects some information

  - most importantly location information (e.g. under MacOSX by using the CoreLocation framework)
  - IP address
  - ...
- sends those information via mail or other ways somewhere
- opens a tunnel to localhost by connecting via SSH somewhere

It should be simple because I want to develop my own solution and just use this as a base.

This is intended for the case that my computer gets stolen so that I might be able to track it back (if it doesn't get completely reinstalled).

Comment: Then you just want software to track your computer if it gets stolen, of which there are *plenty*. Have you searched? ("Tracking software, anti-theft software", etc.)

Comment: @slhck: Yes exactly, that is what I wrote in the question. And I haven't found any which meet my first three criterions.

Comment: I guess the problem is that most of these come consumer-ready, also not for free, and there's no market for an open-source version. I'd be interested too if there's something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open source anti-theft solution for Mac, PCs & Phones – Prey](http://preyproject.com/)

[Adeona: A Free, Open Source System for Helping Track and Recover Lost and Stolen Laptops](http://adeona.cs.washington.edu/) (currently there's only an experimental release for OS X)

(Via iusethis searches for [tracking](http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/tracking) and [theft](http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/theft), not actually tested.)

Comment: Prey seems to be down. Adeona doesn't give me geo location information (although it provides other nice features, e.g. also webcam images).

Comment: Found the Prey source code: https://github.com/tomas/prey and https://github.com/tomas/prey-modules

Answer (score 0):

Some code from Chrome:

- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/browser/geolocation/
- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/geolocation/